# How to edit style of React native tabs in a tab navigation display

Tags: android, react-native

How to edit the style of React native tabs in a tab navigation display to look like this

[image: light mode]

right now the tabs only look like the above image in android light mode
but when I switch the phone's theme to a dark theme on android it looks like this

[image: dark mode]

Which is bad and not the way I want to display

see my code below

```
//AuthTabs.js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

import SignIn from './tabs/SignIn';
import SignUpPhoneVerify from './tabs/SignUpPhoneVerify';
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function AuthTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignIn}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          tabBarLabel: 'Login',
          activeTintColor: '#fff',
          inactiveTintColor: 'ffffff',
          activeBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#CE4418',
          },
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="SignUpPhoneVerify"
        component={SignUpPhoneVerify}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          tabBarLabel: 'Register',
          activeTintColor: '#fff',
          inactiveTintColor: 'ffffff',
          activeBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          inactiveBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#CE4418',
          },
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep it the same for dark theme also?

Answer (score -1):

You could override the dark theme like [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/custom-dark-theme)

Comment: when I do what you said, see the error I keep getting----- ERROR  Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.--- and when i pass 'independent={true}' , my navigation to new screen does not work eg: when users login

Comment: Did you checkout my expo sample, it works as expected.

Comment: your example does not use real screen components. My code does and I told you the error your code sample made my project have. thanks but unless you use real screen components that work, your code has not solved the issue i have

Comment: What do you mean with real screen elements?

Comment: i mean screens that are exported

Comment: I don’t care what you mean, but when my guess is right, it doesn‘t matter whether a screen is exported or not.

Could you explain what do you mean with exported screen?
Is a exported screen, one which is another file?